# Being Prevented From Closing File in Python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to place scores from a 2D Array in to a file and I have arranged them in to descending order and the top highest scores will be put in to a text file for it to be read.

```
def highScoresList(player,score):
    length = len(winners)
    winners.append("")
    winners.insert(length, player)
    winners.insert(length, score)
    if length == 0:
        length = length
    else:
        for x in range (0,length):
            if winners[[x][1]] < winners[[x+1][1]]:
                temp = winners[x]
                winners[x] = winners[x+1]
                winners[x+1] = temp
                length += 1
if length <= 5:
    count = len(winners)
    if count < 5:
        for x in winners:
            high_scores = open("diceScores.txt","w")
            high_scores.write("",winners[[x][0]," - ",winners[[x][1]],""]
            **high_scores.close()** # Invalid Syntax
        high_scores = open("diceScores.txt","r")
        print(high_scores.read())
        high_scores.close()
    else:
        high_scores = open("diceScores.txt","a")
        for x in range (0,4):
            high_scores.write("",winners[[x][0]," - ",winners[[x][1]],""]
            high_scores.close()
        high_scores = open("diceScores.txt","r")
        print(high_scores.read())
        high_scores.close()
```

When I run the code, there is a syntax error on `high_scores.close()`> on the 7th line. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Showing the actual error with surrounding lines would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is a missing close parenthesis on the line before `close`.  It should be:

```
high_scores.write("",winners[[x][0]," - ",winners[[x][1]],""])
```